# UIPickerView changes to normal textField when clicked on alert with TextField

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I have a text Field say jobTextFiels whose inputView is UIPickerView and inputAccessoryView is a UIToolBar. On click of done button(in toolbar) an alert appears whose style is plainTextStyle, if row selected from picker contains text "Others". My problem is that if user selects 'others' from picker and click the add button on alert, then normal keyboard appears for jobTextField.  I have tried each and everything i.e resigning this textfield where ever possible but nothing worked for me.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    _jobTypeTxtFld.inputView = pickerView;
    _genderTxtFld.inputView = pickerView;

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                           nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    _jobTypeTxtFld.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
    _genderTxtFld.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

- (void)doneWithNumberPad{

    if (_jobTypeTxtFld.isFirstResponder) {
        if ([self.jobTypeTxtFld.text isEqualToString:@"Others"])
        {
            [UITextFieldAnimation moveContainerToInitialPositionWithView:self.bgView];
            jobAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Please enter your job type" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add",nil];
            jobAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
            [jobAlert show];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.addrssTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    //[self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        {

        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            if (alertview == jobAlert) {
               // [_jobTypeTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
                [[jobAlert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
                if ([[jobAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString:@""])
                {
                    [UITextFieldAnimation getAlertWithTitle:@"Message" andMessage:@"Please enter your job type!"];
                    [[jobAlert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
                }
                else
                {
                    self.jobTypeTxtFld.text = [jobAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
                    [[jobAlert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
                }
                [_jobTypeTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

#pragma mark
#pragma mark <UIPickerViewDataSource>
#pragma mark

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - picker delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(_jobTypeTxtFld.isFirstResponder)
    {
        [self.jobTypeTxtFld setText:[jobTypeArr objectAtIndex:row]];

    }
    else if(_genderTxtFld.isFirstResponder)
    {
        NSArray *arr = @[@"Male",@"Female"];
        [self.genderTxtFld setText:[arr objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
}


// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if(_jobTypeTxtFld.isFirstResponder)
    {
        return [jobTypeArr count];

    }
    else
    {
       return 2;
    }


}

// tell the picker the title for a given component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(_jobTypeTxtFld.isFirstResponder)
    {
        return [jobTypeArr objectAtIndex:row];

    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *arr = @[@"Male",@"Female"];
        return [arr objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int sectionWidth = 300;

    return sectionWidth;
}
```

[image: On Click of Resturant server]

[image: When Others is selected from picker and done button is clicked]

[image: On click of add of alerview button]

[image: on click of ok]

[image]

Comment: Which effect do you want?

Comment: In the screenshot above, screenshot with alert 'Please enter your job type' uipickerview should not be displayed and in the last screenshot UIPIckerview has changed to normal Keyboard which is wrong. what I want is to disappear picker when user clicks on done button.

Comment: Remove second `if` in `doneWithNumberPad`, that's the place poping up the alert view. Or remove everthing in it and uncomment `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: How could I remove second if, it's the functionality that I want to display alert if others is selected from picker. And yes I have already tried uncommenting [self.view endEditing:YES] but did'nt work.

Comment: Try use endEditing in `alertview clickedButtonAtIndex` The picker during the alert is because `_genderTxtFld` is still the firstResponder.

Comment: try this one  myText.editable = YES;
     [myText becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: @zcui- I hav already tried that.. nothing is working.

Comment: @Birendra - Thanks, it solved my problem to some extent. Atleast now it's showing the correct pickerview.

Answer (score 0):

On clicking done button call method `regisignFirstResponder`. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried each and everything. I have resigned textField where ever possible like on done Button click, On alert view click. But it appears again when alert with textField is shown. This problem is occurring because of alert that contains TextField

Comment: Then you have to write some condition such that alert containing textfield do not appear

Comment: In which iOS are you getting issue?

Comment: it's not related to iOS version. It's because of alertview with TextField

Comment: from ios 8 alertview is depricated thats why asking. Is may be creating issue.

Comment: Yeah I know that. causing Problem in iOS 9. But works well if I use normal alertView without textField.

Comment: Just try with `UIAlertController``